# Ruby: How to hook a callback through inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, callback, hook

I've got some troubles with Ruby about callbacks (and inheritance). Here is my code:

```
class Lmao
  def initialize
    @str = "HAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAH"
    @before_laughing = []
  end

  def self.inherited(base)
    base.extend(Callbacks)
  end

  def laughing
    @before_laughing.each {|method| send(method) }
    @str
  end
end

module Callbacks
  def before_laughing(*methods)
    @before_laughing = methods
  end
end

class Lol < Lmao
  before_laughing :downcase_please

  def downcase_please
    @str.downcase!
  end
end

a = Lol.new
a.laughing # => "HAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAH"
```

And as you can see, my before laughing callback don't work... because the array @before_laughing is empty.  I believe this can be fixed by editing the way I save *methods into an Lol's instance method (from inside Callbacks).  But I don't really see how...

If you know the solution, thanks for your light!

Comment: You made me LOL. And `LOL < Lmao`? I think it should be the *opposite*! :)

Comment: I also thought about it.  But Lmao is more awesome than Lol, so I put it on the top.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to **Mon_Ouie**, the solution is:

```
class Lmao
  def initialize
    @str = "HAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAH"
  end

  def self.inherited(base)
    base.extend(Callbacks)
  end

  def laughing
    self.class.callbacks_before_laughing.each {|method| send(method) }
    @str
  end
end

module Callbacks
  def before_laughing(*methods)
    @before_laughing = methods
  end

  def callbacks_before_laughing
    @before_laughing
  end
end

class Lol < Lmao
  before_laughing :downcase_please

  def downcase_please
    @str.downcase!
  end
end
```

Pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

There are *two* different instance variables called `@before_laughing` in your code: one is an instance variable of *instances* of the `Lmao` class, which gets initialized to `[]` (i.e. an empty `Array`) in `Lmao`'s `initialize` instance methods and gets read in `Lmao`'s `laughing` instance method. However, since the *only* place this instance variable gets written to is the initializer, it will *always* be an empty `Array`.

The other instance variable is an instance variable of the `Lol` class object *itself*, which gets set to the `Array` `[:downcase_please]` inside of the `before_laughing` method. *This* one, however, never gets *read*.

Comment: If I understand, the first instance variables (which you called by: "an instance variable of instances of the Lmao class") is a kinda class variable of Lmao class, isn't it.  Strange; I don't really find the way.